# Is $T = \{ ((A,B), A \times B) : A, B \in P(X) \}$ a function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

Given a set $X$, we have a relation $T$ from $P(X)\times P(X)$ to $P(X \times X)$ so defined :

$$T = \{ ((A,B), A \times B) : A, B \in P(X) \}$$

Is $T$ a function? Is it onto or ono to one?

Comment: Please tell in the question what did you try ?  And where are you stuck ?

Comment: the fact that you can/may write $A\times B$ implies...

Comment: I hope that the upvote is addressed to the "benefactor" that formatted the post ...

Comment: @Lærne  i'm not sure about the difference between $P(X)\times P(X)$  and $P(X \times X)$ and basically confused about how to approach the Q.

Comment: Sorry I'm late.  For the difference between $P(X) \times P(X)$ and $P(X\times X)$, think $X=\mathbb R$.  Then, to get something in $P(X) \times P(X)$, you must choose a left subset and a right subset and in the end, you have a pair of subset like $([0,1), \mathbb Q)$.  For the latter, you can choose any subset of $\mathbb R^2$, like $\{(x,y) : x = ky, k \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.  The former is a pair of subsets, the latter a subset of pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show that $T$ is a function, you need to prove that for each pair of subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ there is one and only one subset $U$ of $X\times X$ such that $T(A,B)=U$, that is, $((A,B),U) \in T$.
Given the definition of $T$, it is quite clear that this is so, taking $U=A\times B$, since $((A,B),A\times B)\in T$ and if $((A,B),U)\in T$, then $U=A \times B$.

I'll leave it to you to show that $T$ is one-to-one (straightforward).
About it being onto, I'll leave you a hint: let 
$$\Delta_X = \{(x,x): x \in X\}.$$
Certainly you have $\Delta_X \in P(X\times X)$.
Can you find $A,B\subseteq X$ such that $A\times B=\Delta_X$?